# User registration in Android app: get friends using app

Tags: android, authentication, sms, registration

I need to add user registration in my app. I want to show to the user using my app, which of his friends are using the same app. The problem is to get his friends.

I don't want to use Facebook or Twitter to get the friendslist. For the sms registration I need a SMS gateway, which is not free of charge.

Is there another possibility to get the friends of the user who use my app?